# How to choose threshold for gensim Phrases when generating bigrams?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, lda, gensim

I'm generating bigrams with `from gensim.models.phrases`, which I'll use downstream with TF-IDF and/or gensim.LDA

```py
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases, Phraser

# 7k documents, ~500-1k tokens each. Already ran cleanup, stop_words, lemmatization, etc
docs = get_docs()

phrases = Phrases(docs)
bigram = Phraser(phrases)
docs = [bigram[d] for d in docs]
```

`Phrases` has `min_count=5`, `threshold=10`. I don't quite understand how they interact, they seem related? Anyway, I see `threshold` having values in different tutorials ranging 1->1000, described as important in determining the number of bigrams generated. I can't find an explanation on how to come by a decent value for one's purposes, simply "fiddle and what works best for you". Is there any intuition / formula for choosing this value, maybe something like "if you want x% more tokens added to your dictionary, use y"; or "if your corpus size is x, try y"? I also see `scoring='default'` can be set to `'npmi'` instead. From the [linked paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf), they say `and t is a chosen threshold, typically around 10e−5`. Might that be a decent approach if I just want this to work "good enough" without needing to fiddle much? That is, `phrases = Phrases(docs, scoring='npmi', threshold=10e-5)`.

TL;DR: is there a simple or intuitive way to choose a decent `threshold` (eg, based on corpus size); alternatively would `scoring='npmi',threshold=10e-5` be simpler?

Comment: I also would be really interested in this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Since `min_count` and `threshold` are hyperparameters, better values could be found through cross validation. Evaluate a range of values to empirically find the values that have the highest performance on a validation set.